# Is there a special pronunciation following a surname which inserts a 사잇소리?

Tags: names

Watching a Korean TV series, I noticed that the name of the antagonist 지청신 is consistently pronounced as if it were, phonetically, **짓**청신. It sounds similar to me to how the first syllable of a word like 숫자 might be pronounced.

Am I hearing correctly that there is a 받침 pronounced at the end of the family name, which is not indicated in writing?

Answer (score 1):

1. No there isn't any special pronunciation rule to insert 사잇소리 in a surname.
2. When you say '지청신' sounds like how first syllable of '숫자' would sound you are kind of right. In Korean pronunciation rules we define it the other way around.
   '숫자' should be pronounced as '수짜' because it has 사이시옷 before 'ㅈ' sound.
   I think you are hearing '지쩡신' (which sounds pretty similar to '지청신') and translating it into '짓정신' with 사이시옷 rule applied.

Reference : https://kornorms.korean.go.kr/regltn/regltnView.do?regltn_code=0002&regltn_no=346